# Change element height using Angular JS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Is there a better way to change an element height using angular js?

I'm doing it like:

```
function HomeCtrl ($scope) {
    $('.banner').css('height', ($(window).height()) - $('.header').outerHeight());
}
```

Comment: Yup, use a directive. If at all possible, don't use jquery in controller. Angular best practice is to manipulate DOM elements in directives.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Avoid jQuery all together. Use a directive and you can access the element and make adjustments to it. As a general rule of thumb, if you have brought in jQuery to help you do DOM manipulation, you are likely doing Angular wrong. Without a lot of context its hard to suggest a better implementation than what you have here.

It somewhat depends on what (and where) `.header` is, but here's my idea:

jscript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('banner', function ($window) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

            var winHeight = $window.innerHeight;

            var headerHeight = attrs.banner ? attrs.banner : 0;

            elem.css('height', winHeight - headerHeight + 'px');
        }
    };
});
```

html:

```
<div banner="250" class="banner">I'm a banner!</div>
```

Since I am not sure what header is, I just assume have it get passed in as an attribute. My best guess for that would be to grab its height and store it in a controller scope that is then watched by banner. This would make it somewhat responsive as well.

Comment: Could you provide an example though, with an implementation not using jQuery?

Comment: @Efren, this example is not using jQuery. $ is for $window is injected angular service.

Answer (score 26):

Don't make DOM manipulations in Controllers. Do it in Directives istead:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('banner', function() {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.height($(window).height() - $('.header').outerHeight());
    }
});
```

And in template:

```
<div banner>foo bar</div>
```

Comment: TypeError: element.height is not a function -> without jQuery this doesn't work.

Comment: @hgoebl Yes, that example needs jQuery as question. `$('.header')` will not work also without jQuery.